# Apache FOP: How to hide table-header from the first page only?

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a document generated using Apache FOP with a multi-pages dynamic table that has a **fo:table-header** with the sum of items from the previous page using **fo:marker** and **fo:retrieve-table-marker**.

```
<fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-row>
        <--! column title cells here -->
    </fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="4">
            <fo:block>Übertrag</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>

        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
                <fo:inline>
                    <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="totalsMarkerHeader"
                                              retrieve-position-within-table="last-ending-within-page"
                                              retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"/>
                </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</fo:table-header>

<fo:table-body>
    <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
        <fo:table-row page-break-inside="avoid">
            <--! data table cells here -->
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:marker marker-class-name="totalsMarkerHeader">
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(preceding::total_price),'€#,##0.00')"/>
                    </fo:marker>
                </fo:block>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-body>
```

This works fine, except that on the first page this row is useless, I would like to remove it from the first page and have it on every other page of the document then.

What I am looking for is an option exactly opposite to the "*omit-header-at-break*" property of the *fo:table*.

I came across the following options of different rendering engines:

1. **fpc:** table-omit-header-at-start="true"
2. **rx:** table-omit-initial-header

... but couldn't find something that works with apache fop.

Is there a workaround to do something similar with Apache FOP and the standard XSL-FO?

---

I also tried to use a conditional visibility for the sum row in the header:

```
<xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <fo:table-row>
    ...
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:if>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like the header condition is evaluated on every page, but is rather done once on the first page making the row invisible on all pages (not just the first page as I would have expected).

Comment: If you showed some markup for how you are using `fo:marker` and `fo:retrieve-table-marker`, we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the table-header and table-body snippets  to my question

Comment: Quite separately, the `fo:block` isn't supposed to be a child of `fo:table-row`.  You could instead put the `fo:marker` as the first child of the `fo:table-row`, where it is allowed.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table-row

Comment: Well it is actually under the table-cell where the value I am aggregating is. I just removed all cells to make it less messy. As mentioned the fo:marker and its retrieval works fine, just want to hide the row from the header of the first page

Comment: @AymanBedair , I am facing the same situation.Let me know  if you have a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

If the section of your document with this table can be isolated into a single page-sequence then:

1) Setup a page sequence with a different first page (so use first and any)

2) In the page template for all pages but the first, create a matching simple one row table in the region before, set to the very bottom so it lands on top of the table in your body. Carefully planned, you can make the little table in the header look like it is a "table-header" even though it is in the page header.

3) Obviously do not put any header on the first page and of course not on the table in the body unless you want to, you can put something completely different here because it would be the region-before of the first page.

4) The you can use regular markers to keep the running total and pull that marker into your table in the header on latter pages.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately the table's content are dynamically generated and the first page has different varying content too before the table starts. I would not be able to extract this part of the document into a single page sequence master :(.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty `fo:marker` that will be picked up by the `fo:retrieve-table-marker` only on the first page.

Comment: My fo:marker holds only the summed subtotal value. I am not sure if I can add the whole row subtotals row as the marker's content !

Comment: You are allowed to put `fo:retrieve-table-marker` as a child of `fo:table-header`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_retrieve-table-marker.

Comment: Ok, that's good. But could I then have fo:table-row and fo:table-cells in the marker ? That would then allow me to add an empty marker in the first page and the whole row later on as you suggested ?